# Optimize call of a view within another view in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have written the following code in Swiftui. The code does not look so nice but it does what it has to do. I was wondering if there are better or cleaner solution to achieve the same effect as my code?
I have 2 views and from the first view I call the other one.

```
struct FirstView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(....){
            ...
            OtherView(uiImage: document.Image)
        }
    }
}



struct OtherView: View {
    var uiImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if uiImage != nil {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code, as written, leaves out details. What is `document`? What is `.Image` on it? Is it meant to represent `OtherView` somehow or are you just passing a parameter to a child view? In general, state should be owned by a common parent and passed down to child views, which it looks like you're probably doing. Not sure if it can be optimized beyond passing a parameter as you're doing.

Comment: Document is a document which includes text and an image. With this OtherView I wanna display in a Grid-Layout the different images of each document.

Comment: I only wanna pass one parameter to the other view

Comment: Okay -- you can't get any more direct than just passing it as a parameter. It looks like you're on the right track unless there's another layer of complexity I'm not understanding.

Comment: if all you are going to do in `OtherView` is to show the `image`, 
then you could replace `OtherView(uiImage: document.Image) ` by: `if let uiImage = document.Image { Image(uiImage: uiImage) }`